# Centered header with button in the same line

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to create a CENTERED header with button on right.
I already have something like this:

```css
h1{
  text-align : center;
  margin-right : 32px;
}

button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  right: 32px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div><h1>test</h1><button style="float: right;">test</button></div>
<div style="text-align: center;">text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but in this case header isn't centered to full width page. 
also, if header is too long it should not cover button..

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Is the only button you will have on realtime or do you have more

Comment: only one button, its a icon 32x32(settings)

Comment: @tomloprod text is centered to full width - 32px, not to full width. it is visible where next line is also centered

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @TheDefinitionist i added next line so you can see that "test" header isnt properly centered

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can center the `h1` and position the `button` to the right:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: I thought he meant the text should be in the header also

Comment: @kukkuz this one works like charm! :) thank you. i tried other answers, but this one is the best. (just added top margin to button so it will be in one line with header)

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by using `flex-box` or `floats`.
You also have to slightly modify your markup.

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

FlexBox:

```
.header {
  display: flex;
}

.header h1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Floats:

```
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header button {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
        .div-header{
            width: 95%;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .div-btn{
            width: 5%;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="div-main">
        <div class="div-header">
             <p>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</p></div>
        <div class="div-btn"><button>Button</button></div>
    </div>
```